# Deleted Ubuntu partition, stuck at GRUB command line

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I am having one big problem. I had dual-boot on my PC: I had Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Yesterday I upgraded to Windows 10 and I deleted the partition where Ubuntu was installed.

When I restarted my laptop it says `grub rescue`. I tried with these commands: `ls`, `set`, `root` but when I type `insmod nomral` it says unknown file system. Also when I try `ls (hd0,msdos1,3,4 or 5)`.

I don't have any OS CD or USB and I only have this laptop. I need it so much today.

Comment: @mikewhatever All methods explained there involve using a live medium. OP says he doesn't have any.

Answer (score 0):

Type the following:

```
insmod ntfs
insmod part_msdos
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
chainloader +1
boot
```

If you succeed to get to Windows, you must rewrite the bootloader using something like EasyBCD if you don't have a Windows installation media (DVD or USB).

Comment: Thanks man but it says again not such partition

Comment: @NickyNick what is the output of `ls`?

Comment: Hd0 (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos1)

Comment: You put a space after hd0. Removing the space gets invaly efi file path after chainloader